# How to set wsgi.url_scheme to https in bottle?

Tags: python-2.7, https, wsgi, bottle, openshift

I want to redirect all requests to `http` to `https`.

Is there a generic approach to setting `wsgi.url_scheme` to `https` in a Python 2.7 bottle application?

The general structure of the application is:

```
setup.py  // contains 'install_requires'  
wsgi  
 - myapplication.py  // the custom application containing bottle routes
```

`wsgi.url_scheme` seems to be related to environment variables:

http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/definitions.html#envvar-wsgi.url_scheme

But I'm not sure how to actually 'set' the environment variable to `https` and whether it can be done in the `setup.py` or `myapplication.py` files.

There is a snippet of code here:

https://github.com/defnull/bottle/issues/347

```
def i_am_https_dammit(app):
    def https_app(environ, start_response):
        environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'
        return app(environ, start_response)
    return https_app
```

But I don't know how I could implement the gist of this, as my call to the application is from [cork](https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/bottle-cork/blob/master/examples/simple_webapp_using_mongodb.py#L38) and just uses:

```
application=default_app()  
session_opts = {
    'session.cookie_expires': True,
    'session.encrypt_key': 'please use a random key and keep it secret!',
    'session.httponly': True,
    'session.timeout': 3600 * 24,  # 1 day
    'session.type': 'cookie',
    'session.validate_key': True,
}
application = SessionMiddleware(application, session_opts)
```

Comment: What WSGI server are you using and what HTTP proxy front end if any? If the original request as received by the WSGI server was actually https over a SSL connection, then the WSGI server should be setting wsgi.url_scheme correctly to https. If it doesn't the WSGI server is broken. If using a proxy front end, with the proxy receiving it as https but then proxying as http, then special configuration is required in the front end proxy so it can tell the backend what the original scheme was so the back end can do a fiddle to accommodate the change from https to http.

Comment: From Bottle's documentation, I would say I am using Bottle's [built in default server](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#server-options) based on wsgiref WSGIServer.  I am not sure what a 'HTTP proxy front end' is.  Currently the site can be accessed at `https`.  If a user goes to `http://site` however I want them to be redirected to `https://site`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm not understanding your question, but why not just install a simple redirect plugin for your Bottle app?  Something like this:

```
import bottle

app = bottle.app()

def redirect_http_to_https(callback):
    '''Bottle plugin that redirects all http requests to https'''

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        scheme = bottle.request.urlparts[0]
        if scheme == 'http':
            # request is http; redirect to https
            bottle.redirect(bottle.request.url.replace('http', 'https', 1))
        else:
            # request is already https; okay to proceed
            return callback(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

bottle.install(redirect_http_to_https)

@bottle.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'hello\n'

bottle.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

Tested with curl:

```
% 05:57:03 !3000 ~>curl -v 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello'
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /hello HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 303 See Other
< Date: Sun, 01 Dec 2013 10:57:16 GMT
< Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: https://127.0.0.1:8080/hello
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

---

For details on how plugins work, see the [Bottle docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/plugindev.html).

Briefly, this plugin works by intercepting all requests and checking the protocol ("scheme").  If the scheme is "http", the plugin instructs Bottle to return an HTTP redirect to the corresponding secure (https) URL.

Comment: I don't know how it works but it does, thank you.  Now I will try and figure out how it works.

Comment: Happy it helped!  I added a couple of sentences that explain it at a high level, plus a pointer to the Bottle plugin docs.