# Redirect all non-www requests to www in bottle-py

Tags: python, bottle

I want to issue a `301` redirect for all requests with a host different than the one identified as *canonical*.

Something like the following, without replicating it in every route:

```
CANONICAL_HOST = 'www.example.com'
@app.route('/')
def home():    
    if request.urlparts.netloc != CANONICAL_HOST:
        redirect_url = request.urlparts._replace(netloc=CANONICAL_HOST).geturl()
        return redirect(redirect_url, 301)
    ...
```

Comment: Just making sure I understand your question. Your redirect is working, but you currently have to repeat the above code for every route. Your question is about how to avoid that duplication, correct? And not about the redirecting per se.

Comment: @ron rothman correct, it's about avoiding duplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found [this 2013 SO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311393/309917) and I adapted it to my needs:

```
from bottle import Bottle, request, redirect

class RedirectToCanonicalURLPlugin():
    api = 2 
    CANONICAL_HOST = os.environ.get('CANONICAL_HOST')
    def apply(self, callback, route):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return (callback(*args, **kwargs)
                if request.urlparts.netloc == self.CANONICAL_HOST 
                else self._redirect())
        return wrapper  
              
    def _redirect(self):
        return redirect(request.urlparts
            ._replace(netloc=self.CANONICAL_HOST).geturl(), 301)

app = Bottle()
app.install(RedirectToCanonicalURLPlugin())
```